# Jenkins Sonar plugin throws duplicate source file error during analysis

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have set up Sonar with MySQL Database. My project is a multi module eclipse project, which means it has multiple plugins. 
I have set up a Jenkins build with Maven to build this project and also installed Jenkins Sonar plugin to analyse the code with sonar. 
All the configurations seem to be correct. However, when sonar tries to analyse this project after the build, it complains of duplicate source code and the build fails.
Each eclipse plugin has Activator.java class and Sonar complains that this is duplicate. I have excluded this class from analysis, but Sonar complains of classes in a particular plugin that is added as a dependency to lot other plugins. 
Incomplete analysis of the code leads to other issues in Sonar for this project. like, even though the project is visible in the Sonar dashboard, it asks for authentication again on clicking the project, even though I am logged in as admin.

Any inputs on pointing me to the right direction would be very helpful.

Please let me know if any additional inputs are necessary to better understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by removing the *test* tag in the parent pom.xml. This was somehow causing sonar to throw the duplicate source error. It was a tedious task to figure out the root cause and I had to reconstruct pom.xml from scratch, adding section by section.

Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "test" tag? I also have "duplicated class" error with maven-compiler-plugin 3.3 but only when building with sonar. Please give me more details about this "test" tag.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the best example you can follow is our Sonar Eclipse project: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse. This is also a multi-module Eclipse project.

In this example, you want to have a look at the parent module (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse/tree/master/org.sonar.ide.eclipse.parent) which goal is only to define the parent POM. Almost everything happens there.

I guess that you should find your way thanks to this.

Comment: Thank you Fabrice. I definately think you are pointing me to the right direction. I did not completely get your first question about only one Sonar project. As mentioned, I am using Maven to build my project and I have a root pom.xml that is parent to all the modules and I have a pom.xml that lists all the modules which extends the root pom.xml. I am giving this pom.xml as the root pom in the sonar configuration in Jenkins build job. Can you shed some more light on defining Sonar modules. As imple example will get me thinking in the right direction.